# how to recognize collision between shapes

Tags: java, 3d

I want to write a program in which I must recognize whether shapes collide together or not. I suspect that I must use class [`WakeupOnCollisionEntry`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/WakeupOnCollisionEntry.html), but I don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: Added link; copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it, but the example in [*Collision Detection with Java3D*](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/collision-detection-with-java3d-2-2.html) looks instructive.